# C++/CX WinRT File Copy

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm really suffering through the WinRT Windows::Storage namespace with all it's asyncronousness.

I have the following private members in my header file:

```
//Members for copying the SQLite db file
Platform::String^ m_dbName;
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ m_localFolder;
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ m_installFolder;
Windows::Storage::StorageFile^ m_dbFile;
```

And I have the following code block in my implementation file:

```
//Make sure the SQLite Database is in ms-appdata:///local/
m_dbName = L"DynamicSimulations.db";
m_localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
m_installFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

auto getLocalFileOp = m_localFolder->GetFileAsync(m_dbName);
getLocalFileOp->Completed = ref new AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StorageFile^>([this](IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^ operation, AsyncStatus status)
{
    m_dbFile = operation->GetResults();

    if(m_dbFile == nullptr)
    {
        auto getInstalledFileOp = m_installFolder->GetFileAsync(m_dbName);
        getInstalledFileOp->Completed = ref new AsyncOperationCompletedHandler<StorageFile^>([this](IAsyncOperation<StorageFile^>^ operation, AsyncStatus status)
        {
            m_dbFile = operation->GetResults();
            m_dbFile->CopyAsync(m_localFolder, m_dbName);
        });
    }
});
```

I get a memory access violation when it gets to `m_dbFile = operation->GetResults();`

What am I missing here? I come from a c# background in which this is really easy stuff to do :/

I've tried using '.then' instead of registering the event but I couldn't even get those to compile.

thank you for your help!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at your code yet, but as a synchronous alternative, consider CopyFile2, which can be called from a Windows Store app.

Comment: yes, that looks much better :)

Comment: This links explain the asynchronous programming model with C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx

Comment: Try replacing the `this` with `=` in the variables to be captured inside the lambda. But `=` will only capture those variables that in the same scope of the lambda. If the variables `m_installFolder`, `m_localFolder` and `m_dbName` are in the same scope as the lambda then its fine. If not, mention them explicitly in between the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the WinRT solution, here it is:

It seems all you want to do is to copy the DB file from the installed location into the local folder.  For that the following code should suffice:

```
//Make sure the SQLite Database is in ms-appdata:///local/
m_dbName = L"DynamicSimulations.db";
m_localFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
m_installFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

create_task(m_installFolder->GetFileAsync(m_dbName)).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{
    create_task(file->CopyAsync(m_localFolder, m_dbName)).then([this](StorageFile^ copiedFile)
    {
        // do something with copiedFile
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this thing before. Don't do this:

```
if(m_dbFile == nullptr)
```

Instead verify the value of "status".

```
if(status == AsyncStatus::Error)
```